# Toggle Layers in Web WorldWind

Tags: javascript, worldwind, webworldwind

I'm new to Web WorldWind and forgive me if this is a simple question, but I haven't found a solution in the documentation or elsewhere. I have the following:

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: 5px; left: 5px;">
    <!-- Create a canvas for Web WorldWind. -->
    <canvas id="canvasOne" width="1040" height="630">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
</canvas>
</div>

<script>
var wwd;
window.addEventListener("load", eventWindowLoaded, false);

// Define the event listener to initialize Web WorldWind.
function eventWindowLoaded() {
    // Create a WorldWindow for the canvas.
    wwd = new WorldWind.WorldWindow("canvasOne");
    // Add some image layers to the WorldWindow's globe
    //wwd.addLayer(new WorldWind.BingAerialWithLabelsLayer());.
    wwd.addLayer(new WorldWind.BingRoadsLayer());

    // Add a compass, a coordinates display and some view controls to the WorldWindow.
    wwd.addLayer(new WorldWind.CompassLayer());
    wwd.addLayer(new WorldWind.CoordinatesDisplayLayer(wwd));
    wwd.addLayer(new WorldWind.ViewControlsLayer(wwd));
}
</script>
```

When the map is displaying, I'd like to add a toggle to switch between the roads layer and the high resolution aerial window. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Set the boolean `enabled` property to show/hide an individual layer.

```
// Create the roads and aerial imagery layers and set the initial visability
var aerialLayer = new WorldWind.BingAerialWithLabelsLayer(),
    roadsLayer = new WorldWind.BingRoadsLayer();
aerialLayer.enabled = true;
roadsLayer.enabled = false;

// Add the layers to the WorldWindow (globe)
wwd.addLayer(aerialLayer);
wwd.addLayer(roadsLayer);

// Toggles the display of the roads and aerial imagery layers
function toggleLayers() {
    aerialLayer.enabled = !aerialLayer.enabled;
    roadsLayer.enabled = !roadsLayer.enabled;
}
```

FYI: The `WorldWindow` (wwd) object has a `layers` array property where you can access the layers.

See: [WorldWind.Layer](https://nasaworldwind.github.io/WebWorldWind/Layer.html)

See also: [layers in WorldWind.WorldWindow](https://nasaworldwind.github.io/WebWorldWind/WorldWindow.html)